# Host discovery using UDP broadcast

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, udp, subnet

I am trying to write a program in **C** to discover **hosts on my subnet** by boradcasting through **UDP** protocol and then counting the number of ICMP_PORT_UNREACHABLE messages.

My code

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{   
    //Take port number as user input
    in_port_t port=htons((in_port_t) atoi(argv[1]));

    struct sockaddr_storage deststorage;
    memset(&deststorage,0,sizeof(deststorage));
    size_t addrsize=0;

    char recvbuff[100];
    struct sockaddr_in clientaddr;
    int clientlen=sizeof(clientaddr);

    //creating sockaddr_in for some random port
    struct sockaddr_in recvsock;
    memset(&recvsock,0,sizeof(recvsock));
    recvsock.sin_port=htons(34234);
    recvsock.sin_family=AF_INET;
    recvsock.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    //destination address for broadcasting
    struct sockaddr_in *da=(struct sockaddr_in *) &deststorage;
    da->sin_family=AF_INET;
    da->sin_port=port;
    da->sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_BROADCAST;

    addrsize=sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    struct sockaddr *destadd=(struct sockaddr *)&deststorage;

    //Take message to be sent as command line argument
    size_t msglen=strlen(argv[2]);

    //creating socket
    int sock=socket(destadd->sa_family,SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_UDP);

    int broadcastperm=1;
    if(setsockopt(sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_BROADCAST,&broadcastperm,sizeof(broadcastperm))<0)
        perror("setsocket failed\n");

    if(bind(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&recvsock,sizeof(recvsock)) == -1)
        perror("Bind error");

    for(;;)
    {
        printf("sending broadcast\n");
        ssize_t nbytes=sendto(sock,argv[2],msglen,0,destadd,addrsize);
        if(nbytes<0) perror("sendto failed");
        else if(nbytes!=msglen)
           perror("size diff");

        int n = recvfrom(sock, recvbuff, 100, 0,(struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr, &clientlen);
        if (n < 0)
            perror("ERROR in recvfrom");
        else
            printf("received reply from %s:%d\n",inet_ntoa(clientaddr.sin_addr),(int)ntohs(clientaddr.sin_port));

        //Prevent network congestion
        sleep(3);
    }
}
```

What I am basically doing in this code is :-

1. First create a UDP socket and bind it to some random higher port number with broadcast option on
2. Send broadcast to 255.255.255.255
3. And then wait for reply from hosts.

What my issue in this code is that it **blocks at recvfrom** and doesn't receives replies from other hosts.

If this issue is due to the fact that this **socket isn't connected** therefore it might not be receiving ICMP error but when I tried after connecting the socket to 255.255.255.255 after that also socket doesn't receives any replies but it just **blocks** there.

Comment: I don't think ICMP errors are sent in response to broadcast messages.

Comment: So how do hosts respond ?

Comment: They only respond if they ARE running a server on the port. The datagram is sent to the server, and it responds normally.

Comment: OK. So instead of broadcasting with UDP should I send ICMP packet to each IP possible in the subnet and then check for port unreachable error?

Comment: Yes, that's now `nmap` works.

Comment: Why not just use `nmap`?

Comment: regarding statements like: `perror("Bind error");`   This does NOT exit the program.  SO the code will continue to execute, even though critical parts of the 'setup' have failed.  I.E. each call to `perror()` should be followed by `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`   Note: Use braces '{` and `}` around the body(s) of the `if()` statements